# Selenium, combining css issue

Tags: java, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm having an issue with css ( cannot find the proper way how to write it)

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-end col-6">
<button disabled="" class="btn btn-primary disabled">'Text 1'</button>
<button disabled="" class="btn btn-primary disabled">'Text 2'</button>
<button disabled="" class="btn btn-primary disabled">'Text 3'</button>
<button disabled="" class="btn btn-primary disabled">'Text 4'</button>
<button disabled="" class="btn btn-primary disabled">'Text 5'</button>
<button disabled="" class="btn btn-primary disabled">'Text 6'</button>
</div>
```

How can I write it down if I want to select 'Text #3' for example?
And one more, how can I write down smth like `parrent[class='smth'] child['Text 3']`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly you can do something like this:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-end col-6">
  <button disabled="" class="btn btn-primary disabled">'Text 1'</button>
  <button disabled="" class="btn btn-primary disabled">'Text 2'</button>
  <button disabled="" class="btn btn-primary disabled">'Text 3'</button>
  <button disabled="" class="btn btn-primary disabled">'Text 4'</button>
  <button disabled="" class="btn btn-primary disabled">'Text 5'</button>
  <button disabled="" class="btn btn-primary disabled">'Text 6'</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div button:nth-child(2) { background: red; }
```

Example codepen: https://codepen.io/brooksrelyt/pen/ZVMPwR

Comment: nope, cause number of child changes(it's dynamic). It has Text 1, Text 2 and so on. so I need to find through button,that has text 'Text #'.

Answer (score 0):

CSS selector (at least one that is supported by Selenium) doesn't allow to locate elements by text (`:contains()` pseudo-class is not supported). You can try to use XPath like below instead:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'flex-row')]/button[text()='Text 3']
```

Comment: I know how to do through Xpath, But I need Css... 8(

Comment: @DmytroIvanenko , now you also know that you cannot do this with CSS

Answer (score 0):

### You can't

CSS is a markup language. Per [the specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#selectors), the selectors work on structure, not on content.

There was talk of adding a [:contains() pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#content-selectors) but I guess it was scrapped.